# Method Name(int, DateTime) has no supported translation to SQL

Tags: c#, linq

I have a function, `Name(int, DateTime)`, that I'd like to use in a linq2sql query.

Its a simple function that computes the difference between the passed in DateTime object and DateTime.Now using a `TimeSpan`.  I then do some basic math stuff with .TotalHours and the passed in int.  The most complicated function is Math.Pow(double,double).

```
public static double Name(int num, DateTime Timestamp)
{
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime then = Timestamp;

        TimeSpan elapsedSpan = new TimeSpan(now.Ticks - posted.Ticks);
        double t = elapsedSpan.TotalHours;

        return System.Math.Pow(t, num);
}
```

I get this error:

```
Method 'Double Name(Int32, System.DateTime)' has no supported translation to SQL.
```

When running a query like this:

```
var q = from k in db.Stuff
        select new {Name=Name(k.num, k.Timestamp)};
```

I understand that the function cannot be converted to SQL as it currently is written.  Is there a way to convert what I have into something that is SQL useable?

I should note that a ToList() or ToArray() method is not useable because the datatable is large.

Comment: Not the answer but if you are using Datetime values in a database you really ought to use UTC times to avoid any issues around daylight savings time changes where time can go back or leap forward.

Comment: I'm using DateTime2(7) in the DB if that matters. How do I use UTC times in my DB?

Comment: Interesting read about DateTimeOffset in SqlServer 2008: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2009/03/31/the-death-of-datetime.aspx

Comment: Simply use DateTime.UtcNow in your code whenever you want 'now', whether that's a value you need to store, or a comparison you need to make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your conversion is only use when projecting, I suggest that you simply do that bit in .NET instead of in SQL:

```
var q = db.Stuff.Select(k => new { k.num, k.Timestamp })
                .AsEnumerable() // Do further processing in .NET
                .Select(k => Name(k.num, k.Timestamp));
```

Note that I've taken the result out of an anonymous type too, so the type of `q` will just be an `IEnumerable<double>`.

If you *really* need the processing to be done in the database, I suggest you write a user-defined function in SQL yourself and tell LINQ to SQL about that (or make it part of a view that you select from).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This is what I'd contemplated doing, but I was concerned with the performance of AsEnumerable. At what point, ie the number of records in k, should AsEnumerable() not be used.

Comment: @Shawn: Well it's not going to change much about how much data is being transmitted - you were still going to fetch "something" about every record, so it doesn't matter *too* much where that's done. If you'd been doing something like a Sum or a Where clause, that should obviously be done in the database as it can do it much more efficiently than fetching all the data client-side... but in this case I think it's not likely to make much difference.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I implemented this solution.  Pretty simple, but I learned that AsEnumerable doesn't have terrible performance, as I, for some reason, previously suspected.

Comment: @Jon AsEnumerable when used in l2s causes these values to be loaded with data context which makes any calls to Attach throw an exception i.e an item with the same key has already been added. How can we work around this issue still using AsEnumerable

Answer (score 2):

LINQ-to-SQL can't translate arbitrary code methods, as they are IL (it expects "expression trees", which is what lambdas and LINQ query syntax a generate). If you only need this logic in your .NET code, switch to LINQ-to-Objects before calling, I.e.

```
var qry = some complex LINQ query

var data = from row in qry.AsEnumerable()
            select new {
               row.Id,
               Name = YourType.Name(row.Foo, row.Bar)
            };
```

The AsEnumerable() breaks the LINQ composition in two, allowing your managed code to run as normal.

If you need to do something similar *at the database*, then write the code in TSQL as a UDF, then map the UDF into LINQ-to-SQL by dragging it onto the designer. You can then access it as a new method on the data-context, I.e.

```
 select db.Name(row.Foo, row.Bar)
```